# Runtime error: Uncaught(inpromise):reference error:cordova is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to create a small app which launches URL, at first I got error (CANNOT FIND PLATFORM) and there was runtime error that could not find module, those previous errors were solved with help from Stack Overflow.

The app is successfully build and it is visible in real device but it could not launch the URL. If I click the button in ionic serve, I am getting runtime error and the button is also not working in real device.

I have added my .ts and.html file and screenshot of the error.

Home.ts

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';
 import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

 declare var cordova:any;

 @Component({
 selector: 'page-home',
 templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })
 export class HomePage {
 constructor(public platform: Platform) {
 platform = platform;

 }

launch(url) {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_system", "location=true");
});

}

}
```

Home.html

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-title>
    Home
</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="home">
<p>
<button (click)= "launch('https://www.google.de')"> LAUNCH URL </button>
</p>  
</ion-content>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you try to use it by `ionic serve` ?

Comment: NO.,the button is not working in real device too

Comment: then ensured that InAppBrowser is present in plugin folder. Otherwise add it `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`

Comment: @Math10 ..,thank you ..,its working !!!!

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensured that InAppBrowser is present in plugin folder. Otherwise add it `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`